# Does the dependency registered in the autofac container be injected into the action method using the [FromServices] attribute

Tags: c#, autofac, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an Adapter controller that has five action methods. Each action method requires a different dependency. Passing dependencies via the `[FromServices]` is the obvious solution. Since I'm using the autofac container, I registered the type as below in the `ConfigureServices` method

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<PolicyTranslatorFactory>().As<ITranslatorFactory<PolicyTranslatorFactory>>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<AdditionalInterestTranslatorFactory>().As<ITranslatorFactory<AdditionalInterestTranslatorFactory>>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.Populate(services);
Container = builder.Build();
return new AutofacServiceProvider(Container);
```

And when I'm trying to hit the action method, it doesn't get hit. When I debug, I see that the controller constructor is being hit but after that program sends 500(internal server error).

```
[HttpGet("legacy_adapter/policyinformation/{policyNumber}/{effectiveDate:datetime}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Policy>> PolicyInformation(string policyNumber, DateTime effectiveDate,[FromServices] ITranslatorFactory<PolicyTranslatorFactory> translatorFactory)
{
 var adapter = new PolicyService(translatorFactory, _dataAccessor, _baseApiClient);
 return Ok(await adapter.GetPolicyInformation(policyNumber, effectiveDate));
}
```

I'm not sure whether using Autofac I could be getting the dependency injected in the action method. If it cannot then what can be the alternative for my scnenario?

Comment: Do you have the stack trace and error message of the exception ?

Comment: In the logging, I don't any exceptions. Rather I get information like Controller and Action method matched, started, request ended and so on